# opengl making many textures power of 2

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I have many (113) texture images created by blender (one obj and one mtl file that reference textures) that are not power of 2. when I try to render a simple object with single texture (power of 2) it works fine, but for the complex object I described above, it only draw geometries (everything is white and no textures).

Is this because of dimensions of my textures? If yes, is there a solution for making many textures/bitmaps power of two in runtime? (I don't know the dimensions.)

I also doubt if `glbindtexture` is used correctly (I am working on Android.)
First, I call `glgentextures(<number_of_objects>, textureArray)`. Then, in a loop for every object I call the `glbindtexture(..._2D, textureArray[i])` and the GLutils.texImage2D(...). Last, in drawing time, I call `glbindtexture(..., textureArray[i])` and then `gldrawarrays`.

Is there any problem with that?
(Edited) I forgot to say, I'm working with opengl es 1.1 and I read somewhere that opengl es 1.1 doesn't support NPOT textrues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks ok.. Do you get any GL errors? And where..

Comment: No, I dont. The object is drawn fine, but there is no texture.

Comment: by the way, when I bind some random POT (power of two) texture, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this method to check for OpenGL driver state errors:

```
public void checkGlError(String op) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e("ShadingZen", op + ": glError " + error);
            //throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
    }
 }
```

Depending on your testing device, it may not be possible to use non power of two textures. This code shows you how to convert them to ^2 sizes (in android):

```
int calculateUpperPowerOfTwo(int v)
{
    v--;
    v |= v >>> 1;
    v |= v >>> 2;
    v |= v >>> 4;
    v |= v >>> 8;
    v |= v >>> 16;
    v++;
    return v;

}

boolean isPowerOfTwo(int i){
    return ( i & (i - 1)) == 0;
}


boolean loadAsTexture2D(Context context, String id, int resource_id, BitmapTexture.Parameters params){
    _bmps = new Bitmap[1];
    Matrix flip = new Matrix();
    flip.postScale(1f, -1f);

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap textureBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource_id, opts);

    if(!isPowerOfTwo(textureBmp.getWidth()) || !isPowerOfTwo(textureBmp.getHeight())){
        int target_width = calculateUpperPowerOfTwo(textureBmp.getWidth());
        int target_height = calculateUpperPowerOfTwo(textureBmp.getHeight());

        Log.i("ShadingZen", "Texture id=" + id + " has no power of two dimesions " + textureBmp.getWidth() + "x" + textureBmp.getHeight() + " adjusting to " + target_width + "x" + target_height);

        Bitmap temp =  Bitmap.createBitmap(textureBmp, 0, 0, textureBmp.getWidth(), textureBmp.getHeight(), flip, false);
        _bmps[0] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, target_width, target_height, false);
        temp.recycle();
    } else{
        _bmps[0]  = Bitmap.createBitmap(textureBmp, 0, 0, textureBmp.getWidth(), textureBmp.getHeight(), flip, false);
    }

    textureBmp.recycle();
    // At this point _bmp[0] contains a ^2 bitmap

}
```

Check this class for more info: https://github.com/TraxNet/ShadingZen/blob/master/library/src/main/java/org/traxnet/shadingzen/core/BitmapTexture.java

Comment: Can you briefly say what does this code do? I mean it stretches the image or add point as border?

Comment: It loads an image from an Android raw resource id, then checks if it's a power of two image. If not, finds nearest power of two and rescales. Read the source code in the link, it handles textures easily. hope that helps.

Comment: I used the checkGLError function and I got the error 1281. then I applied your code, there wasn't errors anymore. but now it too slow. (every 4-5 seconds it draws a scene and then black screen) and in my log this appears: eglLockWindowSurface: failed to map the memory for fd=*a number* offs=*another number*

Comment: This code should only be applied at loading, then call Bindtexture during your drawing loop. Shouldn't be slow.

Comment: If loading time is slow, resize your textures at compile time or with any image retouching app.

Comment: that already is. I load textures in onSurfaceCreated. how do I resize?

Comment: You should post your code somewhere so that we can check it and try to spot your problem.

Comment: I posted another question about error described above, and put my code [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751121/rendering-with-many-textures-causes-egllockwindowsurface). thank for your great answer and helping me.

Comment: EDIT: I updated the isPowerOfTwo method. The repo code has been fixed too thanks to a PR.

Answer (score 2):

when you generate your texture, to use non power of 2 textures you need to enable these paramaters

```
glGenTextures(1, &nID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, nID);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //should probably use these
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); //these let you use NPOT textures
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: Hmm...it didn't work. still everything is white and no textures

Comment: Well keep it in your code, its one step closer to you solving your issue, because you definitely need it for non power of 2 textures. Maybe pastebin your code so we can see whats actually going on.

Comment: problem in loading texture solved with TraxNet post. Now I have a new problem described in comments below TraxNet post. Have you any idea about it? if you need my code plz tell. I will post that as fast as i can.